# Separate the logic from the JS file

Tags: javascript

I have created a weather website, it works fine, but the client asked me to separated the logic from the JS file and yes it would be better, but I don't know which part should I move and to which file..
Here is the code:

```
import createHTMLElement from "./element-helper.js";

const getWeather = async (city) => {
    const apiKey = "000";
    const url = `000`;

    const response = await fetch(`${url}`);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);

    const weather = new Weather(data.name, data.main.temp, data.main.feels_like, data.main.humidity, data.wind.speed);
    return weather;
};

const displayCard = async () => {
    const search = createHTMLElement("div", "search");

    const searchBar = createHTMLElement("input", "search-bar");
    searchBar.type = "text";
    searchBar.placeholder = "Sök på ort...";

    const searchButton = createHTMLElement("button");
    const searchIcon = createHTMLElement("svg");

    searchIcon.innerHTML = `
    <svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 24 24" height="1.5rem" width="1.5rem" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M19.023,16.977c-0.513-0.488-1.004-0.997-1.367-1.384c-0.372-0.378-0.596-0.653-0.596-0.653l-2.8-1.337 C15.34,12.37,16,10.763,16,9c0-3.859-3.14-7-7-7S2,5.141,2,9s3.14,7,7,7c1.763,0,3.37-0.66,4.603-1.739l1.337,2.8 c0,0,0.275,0.224,0.653,0.596c0.387,0.363,0.896,0.854,1.384,1.367c0.494,0.506,0.988,1.012,1.358,1.392 c0.362,0.388,0.604,0.646,0.604,0.646l2.121-2.121c0,0-0.258-0.242-0.646-0.604C20.035,17.965,19.529,17.471,19.023,16.977z M9,14 c-2.757,0-5-2.243-5-5s2.243-5,5-5s5,2.243,5,5S11.757,14,9,14z"></path></svg>
    `;

    searchButton.appendChild(searchIcon);

    search.appendChild(searchBar);
    search.appendChild(searchButton);

    document.querySelector("#card").appendChild(search);
    
    const weatherKeyword = await getWeather("stockholm");
    displayWeatherOverview(weatherKeyword);
};

const displayWeatherOverview = (weather) => {
    const overview = createHTMLElement("div", "weather loading");

    const overviewContainer = createHTMLElement("div", "overview");
    const day = createHTMLElement("h2", "day", "Idag");
    const city = createHTMLElement("h2", "city", weather.name);
    const temp = createHTMLElement("h2", "temp", `${weather.temp}°C`);
    const humidity = createHTMLElement("h2", "humidity", `Luftfuktighet: ${weather.humidity}%`);
    const wind = createHTMLElement("h2", "wind", `Vindhastighet: ${weather.wind} m/s`);

    overviewContainer.appendChild(day);
    overviewContainer.appendChild(city);
    overviewContainer.appendChild(temp);
    overviewContainer.appendChild(humidity);
    overviewContainer.appendChild(wind);
    overview.appendChild(overviewContainer);

    document.querySelector("#card").appendChild(overview);
};

class Weather {
    constructor(name, temp, feels, humidity, wind) {
        this.name = name;
        this.temp = temp;
        this.feels = feels;
        this.humidity = humidity;
        this.wind = wind;
    }
}

displayCard();
```

I tried to make other files such as http, DOM but I got confused..

Comment: Kinda weird, in this very limited case there is no benefit to 'separating the logic'. There is barely any logic, unless you count the fetch as 'logic', all the rest is just how to render the fetched data. So there's very little logic here to separate out.

Comment: well, I agree that it's not a too big app and that one should not worry about code separation too much, but putting UI and networking, in separate files is always good.